# JQuery .addClass and .removeClass not working on Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show and hide divs using a button. This code works just fine in Firefox and IE, but for some reason it's not working in Chrome or Safari. The site is using Bootstrap.

```js
function newAdd(addId, rowId) {
  var add = "#" + addId.id;
  var row = "#" + rowId.id;
  var nextNum = Number(add.charAt(4));
  nextNum++;
  var next = "#add" + nextNum;

  $(add).addClass("dontShow");
  $(next).removeClass("dontShow");
  $(row).removeClass("dontShow");
}
```

```css
.dontShow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="row1">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="000-000">Item Name:</label>
      <br />
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="add1">
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <a onclick="newAdd(add1,row2)">
      <button class="btn" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" id="add1" type="button">Add another item?</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="row2">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="000-000">Item Name:</label>
      <br />
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="add2">
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <a onclick="newAdd(add1,row2)">
      <button class="btn" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" id="add1" type="button">Add another item?</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="row3">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="000-000">Item Name:</label>
      <br />
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what should happen is, the user sees the first row and first button and everything else is hidden. They fill out the first row, then click on the button. When clicked, the button goes away and the next row and next button appear showing two rows with one add button at the bottom. If they click it again, then the last row should appear and the add button goes away completely.

Comment: `newAdd(add1,row2)` should be `newAdd('add1','row2')`, then `"#" + addId`

Comment: Not an issue, but think about what `var add = "#" + addId.id; $(add).addClass("dontShow");` does: 1) Get ID of the element and create a selector from it. 2) Find the element with the ID in the selector. Notice something? You are trying to find element you already have.

Comment: Trav, Use jQuery Anonymous function and use Event handler ( $().on() ) rather adding directly to onclick.

Comment: @FelixKling because it looks like OP wants to pass the ID, I don't support the whole global var for every id on the page thing

Comment: @Huangism: Me neither, but I would have expected it to work nonetheless.

Comment: @FelixKling then maybe it has something to do with the site setup that is not reflected in the code. http://jsfiddle.net/bu4485v4/ works in chrome and safari for me. Oh it looks like OP has multiple IDs with the same name so it does not work

Comment: @Huangism: Yeah, I didn't expect this though. I guess I never was in this situation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions possible to achieve the result.

**Solution 1**

There are 2 updates that need to be done in your code

In HTML

There should be quotes for stirngs like newAdd('add1','row2')

In JS, no need for addId.id

```
var add = "#" + addId;
```

**Solution 2**

No html update. Only in JS, update

```
var add = "#" + addId.id;
```

to

```
var add = "#" + addId[0].id;
```

Solution 1 - You are passing the id of the element and accessing it in javascript.

Solution 2 - You are passing the HTML Object Collection and then accessing the element and its id property.

Now which solution to go for?

In case you only need Id, you can go for solution 1, as it makes no sense to pass the complete collection just to extract the id which can otherwise be send with the same parameters with just quotes around them.

However, if you need to get some other properties of the element, then go for solution 2.

Comment: In JS, you are passing string and and string object does not have id as property, hence, it will give undefined. And moreover what was needed over there was to only get the element using id selector for which string addition of # and the id passed will work

Comment: But the OP is not passing strings, he is passing elements: `newAdd(add1,row2)`. Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve with your change.

Comment: He is passing html object collection, he just need to extract id, so it is better to pass only that rather than the whole collection. That is what i feel and follow

Comment: Why don't you explain that in your answer? Would have saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Ok. I will do that Felix

Comment: Thanks Felix for suggesting. I will make sure you dont waste time at least with me

Comment: @nikhil you're correct, all I needed was the row id. I must have just left off the quotes. This worked for me.

Comment: @Trav.is.awesome - Good to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work in Chrome or Safari is that `add1`, which you are passing to the function, i.e.

```
addNew(add1, row1);
```

does not refer to a single element, but to an element collection:

[image]

Why? Because you have multiple elements with the same ID. **IDs have to be unique!**

Firefox on the other hand simply takes the first element with that ID (which is what I would have expected).

---

There are a couple of ways to solve this, one of them shown in the other answer, but you should definitely ensure that you are only using unique IDs. I highly recommend to read up on binding event handlers with jQuery: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/